# how to add custom script in shopify without using script tag

Tags: shopify, shopify-api, shopifyscripts

like HT Script application( https://apps.shopify.com/ht-script )。you can add custom script like

```
"var a=1";
```

and we can see custom script in html header like

```
<script>var a=1;</script>
```

i know Shopify API support script tag to add custom script like

```
<script src="http://xxxx.js"></script>
```

so,what's the principle behind HT Sciprt application，why it don't need src 。

Comment: HT, means? need clear information to understand properly.

Comment: https://apps.shopify.com/ht-script ，why HT don't need src 。

Answer (score 0):

App has following permissions:
[image]

That means it uses following access scopes

- read_themes
- write_themes

Way how it probably works

1. Reads list of themes

   GET /admin/api/2021-01/themes.json
2. With that list it can find active theme.

   Field "role" equals "main".
3. With active theme id it can access assets.

   GET /admin/api/2021-01/themes/{theme_id}/assets.json?asset[key]=layout/theme.liquid
4. With content of that file you can modify headers as you want with html parser.
5. Update the same file with another api call

   PUT /admin/api/2021-01/themes/{theme_id}/assets.json

Of course you can create some cron job in your application to make sure that your modified scripts are always up to date with template.

Helpful links:

- [Access scopes in Shopify Rest API](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/access-scopes)
- [Shopify theme Rest API reference](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/online-store/theme)
- [Shopify asset Rest API reference](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/online-store/asset)

Comment: really a good answer ，i get it。another question，the js script content data which i write，HT Script save it to shopify  or HT script own server？

Comment: You can make it two ways.

1.Upload your file to assets
`"asset": {
    "key": "assets/your_script.js",
    "value": "<content>"
  }`

And then include it like this:
`<script src="{{ 'your_script.js' | asset_url }}" defer="defer"></script>`

Or create [script tag](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/online-store/scripttag) that would be loaded on each page of store (you need to host js file)
I suggest first option it would be simpler and faster to implement.